# Symfony2 Doctrine Joint request

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm using doctrine with symfony and in my Entity Advert i created in the repository 2 methods to load data

```
public function getAdvertAccordingToCategories(array $categories){
    $qb = $this -> createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->join('a.categories' , 'cat')
    ->addSelect('cat');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('cat.name', $categories));

   return $qb ->getQuery()->getResult();
}   

public function getAdvertWithContributions(){
    $qb =   $this -> createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->leftJoin('a.condidatures' , 'cond')
    ->addSelect('cond');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

i call them from the controller

```
$listAdverts = $em ->getRepository('boudaplatformBundle:Advert')->getAdvertWithContributions();

 $advertTest = $em ->getRepository('boudaplatformBundle:Advert')->getAdvertAccordingToCategories(array('xxx' , 'yyy'));
```

if i use the second method with arguments that that any advert is in like xxx and yyy everything is fine the first method doesn't return anything and the second returns my Advert entities and her categories

```
 $listAdverts = $em ->getRepository('boudaplatformBundle:Advert')->getAdvertWithContributions();

 $advertTest = $em ->getRepository('boudaplatformBundle:Advert')->getAdvertAccordingToCategories(array('Games' , 'anime'));
```

and when i use category arguments that adverts are part of i have the same adverts but when i loop for the categories of the advert i found only those passed in argument : Games and anime "for both methods "

I really dont understand why in the second case even the datas retrieved from the getAdvertWithContributions() are modified i should receive the same result i think

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is not working as expected. Just the fact, in your second case, that you get only Games and Anime categories ?

Comment: the advert entity E1 has relation with 4 categories Games , Anime , TvShows and Movies so when i use E1 -> getCategories() i have in result only the ones i filtred by in the exemple Games and anime  for both the list of the 2 methods . what i really dont understand is why the result in the first method getAdvertWithContributions() are affected too